# dynamically add colspan value on condition angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to change table header 'th' colspan value on a condition using angular?

Heres what I have tried. this doesnt work, whats wrong here!.

```
<th  ng-attr-colspan={{2}} ng-repeat="header in ::tableHeaders track by $index">'+ '{{header}}</th>
```

or

```
<th  ng-attr-colspan="someFunct()" ng-repeat="header in ::tableHeaders track by $index">'+ '{{header}}</th>
```

or 
This works but I would like to change the value everytime.

```
<th  colspan={{2}} ng-repeat="header in ::tableHeaders track by $index">'+ '{{header}}</th>
```

Comment: should be `colspan="{{colSpan}}"`, where `colSpan` is member of `$scope`

Comment: yeah thats one way, is there a way to call a function on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were just missing quotes for the attribute. Remember that curly braces in AngularJS just provides text instead of expression (and curly braces). there is no more magic.

This will give the desired effect, I think it's the most straightforward way:

```
<th colspan="{{header.cols}}" ng-repeat="header in tableHeaders track by $index">
      {{header.text}}
</th>
```

However, there is an option to call a function for colspan number:

```
  $scope.tableHeaders = [{
    text: 'Header 1',
    cols: 1
  },{
    text: 'Header 2',
    cols: 2
  },{
    text: 'Header 3',
    cols: 1
  }];
  $scope.getColsSpan = function(header){
     //for the sake of example this splits last digit from the text and returns it
    return parseInt(header.text.split(' ').pop());
  };
```

In html: `<th colspan="{{getColsSpan(header)}}" ...`

As proposed, `ng-attr-colspan` can also be used, but it also requires curly braces for expression evaluation

```
     <Th ng-attr-colspan="{{header.cols}}"
```

All options implemented in 
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Xc5ye1jLMiJRK7zJqwk?p=preview)

Comment: this will work for me, just one more thing, ng-attr-colspan cant I use this?